# Do trinkets stack?

Tags: wasteland-2

If I have multiple copies of the same trinket in my inventory, will the effects from it stack?

For instance, say I have two [Ship in a Bottle](http://wasteland.gamepedia.com/Ship_in_a_Bottle) trinkets (one Ship in a Bottle has +1 mechanical skill) in my inventory. Will the character which has them have a total of +1 to mechanical skill or +2 to mechanical skill?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trinkets only provide their bonus when equipped to a character's "trinket" slot. Each character has one trinket slot. Therefore, no, I suppose trinkets don't stack, because each character can only equip one.

Trinkets just sitting in your inventory do nothing. Important for rabbit's feet, which have both bonus and penalty.

Comment: Didn't even see the trinket slot! Hah! Thanks.